# Array copy for a Thread c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm in trouble, I have a cycle that has been executed every almost 200ms and populate 2 arrays, one is a copy of the old one achivied, the other is the new one.

Here is the cycle code:

```
private byte[] _oldBuffer;
private byte[] _newBuffer;

private void Cycle()
{
   while(exitCondition)
   {
     //do other stuff that not involved _newBuffer or _oldBuffer
     GetNewBuffer()
     //other stuff that not involved _newBuffer or _oldBuffer too
     Thread.Sleep(200); //or more, minimum 200
   }
}

private void GetNewBuffer()
{
        _oldBuffer = _newBuffer;

        //retrieve from PLC the new buffer
        _newBuffer = RetrieveNewBuffer();

        Thread checkDifference = new Thread(() => MethodToCall.Start(_oldBuffer, _newBuffer));
        checkDifference.Start();

}
```

And here it is the method executed by the Thread

```
public static void Start(byte[] oldBuffer, byte[] newBuffer)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < oldBuffer.Lenght; i++)
    {
        //here happens that the two buffer are equal even if at starting the process they weren't
        //they could be equal from a read to another, not always something change every 200ms
        if(oldBuffer[i] != newBuffer[i])
            //value has change, handle method
    }        
}
```

My problem is that, in the next read I'll overwrite _oldBuffer and _newBuffer, and the Thread catch them modified and will not find difference (or at least that is what I catch from debugging) from the two, no more different, arrays.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advice to anyone

Comment: That looks like pseudo-code to me... please provide a [mcve]. (I'd also strongly suggest following .NET naming conventions...)

Comment: Easiest solution is to pass a copy of the buffers to the thread method. But that would probably be slower than just making a blocking call to the method (unless the method is relatively slow).

Comment: Minor code style nitpick - those underscores are horrible_for_readability. A significant number of readers would prefer you used *camelCase*. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CamelCase I can thoroughly recommend the visual studio stylecop plugin. It really improved my code.

Comment: Sorry guys, resolved, it was something in the check difference method, an if that never been passed for some corrupted databases. With the Array.Copy() method now it works. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with Array.Copy() and it works, the array are not being changed. Something like that:

```
private void GetNewBuffer_ArrayCopy()
{
        _oldBuffer = _newBuffer;
        _newBuffer = RetrieveNewBuffer();

        byte[] localOldBuffer = new byte[_oldBuffer];
        Array.Copy(_oldBuffer, localOldBuffer, 0);
        byte[] localNewBuffer = new byte[_oldBuffer];
        Array.Copy(_newBuffer, localNewBuffer, 0);

        Thread checkDifference = new Thread(() => MethodToCall.Start(localOldBuffer, localNewBuffer));
        checkDifference.Start();

}
```